# Unable to bind the collection to Listview in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application where i can read some properties from the windows services list which are currently running on my system.I am able to read the properties of a particular service and passing to a collection which in turn show up in my UI under a Listview.

I want the same scenario to be used for list of services .i.e.i am trying in the following way..but i am not sure where did i miss the point...

Here is my code

```
  foreach (string serviceName in sList)
        {
            ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceName);


            StatusCollection.Add (new StatusData 
            { 
                Name = name, 
                Status = status 
            });
        lvStatus.DataContext = StatusCollection;
        lvStatus.ItemsSource = StatusCollection;
        }

 <ListView Height="166" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,0,0,0" Name="lvStatus" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264"  >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the DataContext line of code.

If you set your ItemsSource in the code behind make sure you do it before InitializeComponent is called.  If not, you will need to refresh your Items collection.

However, I would setup a View Model for your Window or Control which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  Create your collection as an ObservableCollection and bind to it in the XAML:

```
<ListView ... ItemsSource={Binding Path=ServiceList}>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Let me know if you need an example of using a View Model.

Comment: I would be happy if i can get an example using ViewModel

Comment: Here are a couple of good links:    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfMvvmQuickStart.aspx.  I'm sure if you do a quick search through Stack Overflow you can find some other ones.